# Adding a space before a character in a string C++ insert function

Tags: c++, string, insert, space

I am attempting to add space before a character in a string by using the insert function.

Can someone kindly explain why the following code does not work ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
{
   if(line[i+1] == '=')
   {
      line.insert(i, " ");
   }
}
```

Comment: Define `doesn't work`

Comment: Please add more specific information about problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert before `=` you can get the index of `=` directly and not the index of char followed by `=`. This could lead to out of bounds access.

Also, when you insert the space you extend your string by 1, that's ok but only if you also adjust the counter `i`, otherwise it will insert again and again and again before `=` resulting in infinite loop. Adjust your code in this manner:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
{
    if (line[i] == '=')
    {
        line.insert(i++, " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly. great explanation as well. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine except for one little detail:

Imagine you have a string with "test=something". When you iterate it, when i is 3 you will find the next character is an equals, so you put a space into it. Next iteration i will be 4, but you just added a space, so at i equals 5 there's the same equals sign. So you put another space and so on. TO fix this youy can try:

```
std::string line = "test=something";
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
{
    if (line[i + 1] == '=')
    {
        i++;
        line.insert(i, " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: or... one can remove the potential out of bounds access, and check `line[i] == '='` instead.

Comment: yes, my bad :P Killzone Kid had a better solution :P